# How to know how many color channels in cv2 VideoCapture object?

Tags: python, opencv, video, colors

I have the following method:

```
def _create_capture_object(self):
    self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self._path_to_video)
    self._width = self._cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    self._height = self._cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    self._frame_rate = self._cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    self._frame_count = self._cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    self._n_channels = self._cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_CHANNEL)
```

Everything works as expected, except

```
    self._n_channels = self._cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_CHANNEL)
```

Which always returns `0.0`

How can I get `1` in case of a gray-scale video, or `3` in case of a color video?

Comment: "Channel" in this situation is not the same thing as it is in a `Mat` (i.e. it doesn't let you distinguish between RGB and grayscale) -- it's used to select from multiple video sources for devices that support it.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! I actually Don't know anything about `Mat`s. I was only referring to number of color channels.

Comment: [`CAP_PROP_FORMAT`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da171e1ed33a7c1280a9d2c869732f226c) would seem to be the right thing, but unfortunately the only backend that [seems to implement it](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/333a767be456d8ce13848b64f8ccd8352af9cfe2/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L1898) is `v4l`... there's also `CAP_PROP_MONOCHROME`, but that doesn't seem to be possible to read in any backend as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah, I meant colour channels by that. Not sure why I didn't think to write that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv2.CAP_PROP_CHANNEL` attribute seems to

> return 0 when querying a property that is not supported by the backend
>   used by the VideoWriter instance.

Quoted from up to date [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#a284e798e95847789024954abeec945d5) of opencv 4.3.

I believe the only way you can get the channel value is by capturing a frame then retriving the shape information of it.

EDIT #1: Thanks to @[Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) I updated my answer corresponding to new documentation.

Comment: You're consulting out of date documentation. If that [property](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da2f6d968016612b1d87c9895e75a6449a) didn't exist, OP would get an error. Unfortunately the meaning of the property is not what OP thinks.

Comment: That said, the suggestion on how to deal with the issue makes sense.

Comment: I was not aware that it was outdated. Thanks for info.